# Where does Spotlight store its metadata index?

Tags: macos, mac, spotlight

Where does Mac OS X store Spotlight comments associated with a file? Is it stored as HFS+ file metadata, or is the information kept by the OS somewhere else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The metadata is inside a hidden `.Spotlight-V100` folder at the root of the indexed volume.

Answer (score 7):

The values of the `kMDItemFinderComment` attributes that get stored in metadata store directories like `/.Spotlight-V100/` depend on the `com.apple.metadata:kMDItemFinderComment` extended attributes.

Finder also stores the Spotlight comments of all items in a folder in a `.DS_Store` file.

You can print Spotlight comments with `mdls` or `xattr`:

`mdls -n kMDItemFinderComment test.txt`

`xattr -p com.apple.metadata:kMDItemFinderComment file.txt | xxd -r -p | plutil -convert xml1 -o - - | ruby -rcgi -e 'puts CGI.unescapeHTML(STDIN.read.scan(/<string>(.*)<\/string>/m)[0][0])'`

If you use Finder to add a Spotlight comment for a file you don't have write permission to (like some application bundles in `/Applications/`), the comment won't be saved as an extended attribute, and it won't get picked up by Spotlight. You can open Finder as the superuser or use `sudo xattr -w` though.

If you delete a `.DS_Store` file from a folder and quit and reopen Finder, the Spotlight comments of all files in the folder disappear from Finder's information windows. If there are still extended attributes for the Spotlight comments, the comments are seen by Spotlight though.

If you use `xattr` to add a `com.apple.metadata:kMDItemFinderComment` extended attribute, the comment gets picked up by Spotligt, but it won't be shown in Finder's information windows.

`xattr -w com.apple.metadata:kMDItemFinderComment comment file.txt`

If you use AppleScript to change the `comment` attribute of a file, the comment is also saved in a `.DS_Store` file and shown in Finder.

`osascript -e 'on run {f, c}' -e 'tell app "Finder" to set comment of (POSIX file f as alias) to c' -e end file.txt comment`

(There is a warning like `CFURLGetFSRef was passed this URL which has no scheme` in 10.8 when a relative path is converted to an alias, but you can ignore it.)

Comment: Please provide a way to verify this. I was unable to do so. Setup: Create folders `foo` and `foo/bar`, use Automator to set Spotlight comment *baz* on `foo/bar`. Open foo in Finder, search for *baz* in it. This finds `foo/bar`. Then open Terminal, delete `foo/.DS_Store` (there's no `foo/bar/.DS_Store`). Relaunch Finder. Open `foo` in Finder, search for *baz*: Still finds `foo/bar`.

Comment: This works for me! Is there a way to write them? I've tried writing to the plist as well as an ascii-encoded hex string and neither sticks. I can write keywords that Spotlight finds using `xattr -w com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags`  Maybe I should write this as a question of its own...

Comment: @beroe I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to edit the spotlight comments on a file, you can see/modify them under the Get Info (command + I) window for the file.