# How do you add a spotlight comment to a folder

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, finder, applescript

How do I set a *spotlight comment* for a folder using Bash. (Or Applescript)

The following example is not working:

```
osascript -e "tell application \"Finder\" to set comments of alias POSIX file \"$folder\" to \"This is a spotlight comment\"
```

Comment: Missing a close-quote on the command as typed. Is that how you were testing, or a transcription error?

Comment: Good spotting! Another crucial miss is the fact it needed to say comment instead of comments!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/256311/226698) to be a function you can define in your `~/.bash_profile` and it seems to work for files or folders:

```
makecomment(){
  osascript -e 'on run {f, c}' -e 'tell app "Finder" to set comment of (POSIX file f as alias) to c' -e end "$1" "$2"
}
```

USAGE:

```
makecomment foldername "My comment"
```